# custom asp.net error on a live site

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have recently migrated an ASP.net web site. I get errors, I assume it's due to database connection.
My question is, is it possible to turn on custom errors, even if I don't have the asp.net project code?
In other words,
**Can I turn on custom errors on the server remotely?**

Comment: Run the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager tool from the Administrative Tools (on the start menu if admin tools are enabled there). Open up the system, and right click on your web site. Select Properties. Choose the ASP.NET tab. Click on "Edit Configuration". Click the Custom Errors tab. Select `On` for custom error mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom errors are managed via the Web.Config.  So all you need is FTP to modify the Web.config.  Otherwise you can look at remotely connecting to IIS if you have that level of rights.

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like to remotely access and configure an IIS server, you'd need to configure Management Service on the server. I have found a detailed article on how to accomplish this, which you can find [here](http://blog.pluralsight.com/iis-7-remote-administration)